TikZ: filling rectangle with random dots trouble
Based on Poisson disc sampling implemented in luatex, my idea is to replicate the microscopic figure of a colloidal solution, that is, to create rectangles whose concentration of points increases from top to bottom.
If I try this way
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=white] (0,0) rectangle ++(1,3);
    \pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
    \foreach \p in {1,...,100}
    { \fill[black]  (4*rand,2*rand) circle (0.05);
    }

    \draw[draw=white] (0,3) rectangle ++(1,3);
    \pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
    \foreach \p in {1,...,500}
    { \fill[black]  (4*rand,2*rand) circle (0.05);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}


Any ideas?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

same question as yesterday?

In the code below, the distribution of the points is specified with rnd^2. Another function can be chosen for a different result. The radius of the dots is determined by \r. The size of the rectangle is determined by \x and \y.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\r{0.05}
\def\x{4}
\def\y{2}
\pgfmathsetseed{24122015}
\foreach\n in {1,...,200}{
  \fill[cyan] (\x*rnd,{\y*rnd^2}) circle[radius=\r];
}
\draw (-\r,-\r) rectangle (\x+\r,\y+\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


